# LaTeX 'Missing $' Cannot find the reason

Tags: math-mode, vector

So i am writing up some maths definitions for my exams and for some reason Texworks says that I have a 'missing $' in my line of work, however I cannot see anything wrong with it.

```
\subsection{Directional Derivative}
Let $\Omega \subset \mathbb{R}^n$ be open and let $f:\Omega \to \mathbb{R}$ be a continuosly differentiable scalar field on $\Omega$. Let $\vec{\hat{a}}$ be a unit vector in $\mathbb{R}^n$ Then:
$$D\hat{a}f(\vec{x_0})=\lim_{h \to 0}\frac{(f(\vec{x_0}+h\vec{\hat{a}}-f(\vec{x_0})}{h}$$
is the \bi{directional derivative} of fin the direction $\vec{\hat{a}}$

\subsection{ $\nabla$ Operator}
The \textit{\textbf{ $\nabla$ or del operator}} is written formally as
$$ \nabla = \frac{\partial}{\partial x_1}\vect{e_1} + \frac{\partial}{\partial x_2}\vect{e_2}+ \dots \frac{\partial}{\partial x_n}\vect{e_n}$$

\subsection{Gradient}
Let $f:\Omega \to \mathbb{R}$ be a continuously differentiable scalar field on an open set $\Omega \subset \mathbb{R}^n$ Then:
$$grad \, f\equiv \nabla f:=\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_1}\vect{e}_1+\dots+\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_n}\vec{e}_n$$ is the \bi{gradient} on $\Omega$ which is itself a vector field. And is obatained by applying the $\nabla$ Operator to the function.

\subsection{Divergence of F}
```

If I ignore the error and force it to finish I get a weird repitition of e_1 getting smaller and smaller and then one partial derivative at the end.

When in fact it should be a sum of partial derivatives.

Does anybody know what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Please post a [minimal working example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) illustrating the error. In particular, include the necessary packages from your preamble for reproducing the error. In particular, how are you defining `\vect{}` or which packages are you loading that provides that command?

Comment: If you format the LaTeX, it is probably much easier to see where it went wrong... a rapid check doesn't show any obvious problem. I'd suggest using `\(...\)` and the `equation` environments, it is easier not to mess them up. The "missing $" is most often for using a math-only construct outside of math.

Comment: Note: unrelated to your problem I think,  but you shouldn't use `$$ ... $$`, see [Why is `\[ … \]` preferable to `$$`?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/503)

Comment: With this `\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts}
\let\vect\vec
\let\bi\emph` as a preamble, I have no problem. So there must be something else hidden in your preamble.

Answer (score 9):

You're inconsistent in your typing.

1. Choose between `\vec{x}_0` or `\vec{x_0}` and stick to the convention; in the example the first form is used, which seems to be more common.
2. Once you have defined `\bi` to give "bold italic", always use it.
3. Be careful with spaces in arguments.
4. Always use `\[...\]` and *not* `$$...$$` (see [Why is \[ ... \] preferable to $$ ... $$?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/503)).
5. `\colon` is preferred to `:` for function notation.
6. Punctuation should be consistent; a colon after "Then" doesn't seem necessary, while final periods *are* necessary. Whether adding them also to displayed equations that end a paragraph or a sentence is a matter of personal taste.
7. Don't use "hand made" operator names such as `grad\,`, prefer the higher level `\DeclareMathOperator` way.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}

\DeclareMathOperator{\grad}{grad}
\newcommand{\bi}[1]{\textbf{\textit{#1}}} % guess

\begin{document}

\subsection{Directional Derivative}

Let $\Omega \subset \mathbb{R}^n$ be open and let $f\colon\Omega \to \mathbb{R}$ be
a continuosly differentiable scalar field on $\Omega$. Let $\vec{\hat{a}}$ be a unit
vector in $\mathbb{R}^n$. Then
\[
D\hat{a}f(\vec{x}_0)=\lim_{h \to 0}\frac{(f(\vec{x}_0+h\vec{\hat{a}}-f(\vec{x}_0)}{h}
\]
is the \bi{directional derivative} of fin the direction $\vec{\hat{a}}$.

\subsection{$\nabla$ Operator}
The \bi{$\nabla$ or del operator} is written formally as
\[
\nabla = \frac{\partial}{\partial x_1}\vec{e}_1 + 
  \frac{\partial}{\partial x_2}\vec{e}_2+ \dots \frac{\partial}{\partial x_n}\vec{e}_n.
\]

\subsection{Gradient}

Let $f\colon\Omega \to \mathbb{R}$ be a continuously differentiable scalar field
on an open set $\Omega \subset \mathbb{R}^n$. Then
\[
\grad f\equiv \nabla f:=
  \frac{\partial f}{\partial x_1}\vec{e}_1+\dots+\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_n}\vec{e}_n
\]
is the \bi{gradient} on $\Omega$ which is itself a vector field. And is obtained
by applying the $\nabla$ Operator to the function.

\subsection{Divergence of $F$}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Actually I'd recommend the `equation*` env over `\[...\]`, but that is just because it is easier to change in Emacs ;-)